# How to prove that $\mathcal{P}(A\cap B)=\mathcal{P}(A)\cap\mathcal{P}(B)$? (Powersets)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am trying to wrap my head around set theory for university, but i am stuck at this problem:

$$\mathcal{P}(A\cap B)=\mathcal{P}(A)\cap\mathcal{P}(B)$$

I know how to prove that two sets are equal, but I am not sure how to do this with powersets?

If someone could explain how i would go about proving this, I would be very grateful.

Comment: They are sets, so the usual method should be applied.

Comment: To show that two sets are equal, you can show that each contains the other. That is, $S=T$ if and only if $S \subseteq T$ and $T \subseteq S$. This is what @Matt Samuel is showing in his answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $C\in \mathcal{P}(A\cap B)$, then $C\subseteq A\cap B$, so $C\subseteq A$ and $C\subseteq B$, so $C\in \mathcal{P}(A)\cap \mathcal{P}(B)$.

If $C\in \mathcal{P}(A)\cap \mathcal{P}(B)$, then $C\subseteq A$ and $C\subseteq B$. Thus $C\subseteq A\cap B$, hence $C\in\mathcal{P}(A\cap B)$.